# cannot get wisps on ghost with point cloud node in blender

Tags: point-clouds

So I am trying to create a cool ghost pony with a particle system with a wind force and vortex behind it that blows upon the pony. I limited the particles life span to end just past to the pony so that it looks like there are cool wisps coming off of it. As one can see, I am using the point cloud node the way that it should be in order to gain such an effect as I would believe. Here is a screen shot attached.You can also see the current render and the file that I attached. I am trying to animate a cool ghost, but this does not seem to be working as I thought it should. There should be wisps coming off of the mesh and there are not. Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lnz23i4frbtms9c/ghost_test.blend?dl=0

[image: attached screen shot of node display and current makeup of work space[![current render of screen shot]ace][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fPE9.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fPE9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[image]So I figured it out. All I had to do was turn my pony into the emitter and then select it and add quick effect smoke to the mesh and use the particle system as the smoke flow. Then bake all of the dynamics.